# condition is not matching but still getting response using below dw code

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

XML "Input"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <XMLDocuments xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:asnfunctions="urn:my-scripts">
    <docket>
        <shipfromlocation>1633</shipfromlocation>
        <shipfromname>GP Corrugated LLC - Asheboro, NC </shipfromname>

    </docket>
</XMLDocuments>
```

datawave code written by me:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var plantDetails =[
  {
    "customerPath": null,
    "plantCode": "1650",
    "salesSystem": "BVP",
    "plantName": "Akron",
    "siteCode": "AK",
    "division": "350",
    "location": "392",
    "mailCode": "OH030"
  },
  {
    "customerPath": null,
    "plantCode": "1651",
    "salesSystem": "BVP",
    "plantName": "Albany",
    "siteCode": "AL",
    "division": "350",
    "location": "386",
    "mailCode": "GA010"
  }
]

---

XMLDocuments:
docket:(flatten (payload.XMLDocuments.*docket default [])  map using (parent=$) {
    (plantDetails filter ($.plantCode !=parent.shipfromlocation ) map using (child=$) {

        shipfromlocation: child.mailCode,
        shipfromname: parent.shipfromname

 })
})
```

Here if condition $.plantCode !=parent.shipfromlocation  is not matching but still getting result , Please help me on the same

Comment: You should post your expected output so people can match your expectation to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is fine. It says $.plantCode != parent.shipfromlocatio (NOT EQUAL) and one of your values (1633) is really nor equal anything.

I guess you mean EQUAL (==) instead? In this case better use ~= - equal to anything ignoring type.

Comment: As  suggested I have tried but still unable to get response , Scenario1 : when I am keeping shipfromlocation as '1650'(matches with plantcode "1650" then I should not get result but still I am getting .Scenario 2 : if I am keeping shipfromlocation  as '1633' with above suggestion so getting expected result for scenario2 but here scenario1 is failing.